# Changing the backcolor of multiple buttons while holding down the mouse button?

Tags: vb.net

I currently have buttons in panel that is located in every cell of a tablelayoutpanel. I want to be able to hold my left mouse button down and drag across the tablelayoutpanel and highlight all the buttons as my mouse goes over in red.

My code to create the Panel and buttons. The tablelayout panel is already created.

```
Private Sub LoadHandMatrix(HandMatrix As TableLayoutPanel)
        Dim Hands As New List(Of String)()
        Dim NRow As Integer = 12
        Dim NCol As Integer = 12
        Dim HandBtnArray((NRow + 1) * (NCol + 1) - 1) As Button
        Dim FrequencyBtnArray((NRow + 1) * (NCol + 1) - 1) As Button
        Dim PanelArray((NRow + 1) * (NCol + 1) - 1) As Panel
        Hands = MatrixHands()

        With HandMatrix
            .Height = 1800
            .Width = 1800
        End With

        For i As Integer = 0 To HandBtnArray.Length - 1
            PanelArray(i) = New Panel
            PanelArray(i).Name = "p" + Str(i)
            PanelArray(i).Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Right
            PanelArray(i).BackColor = Color.White
            HandMatrix.Controls.Add(PanelArray(i), i Mod (NCol + 1), i \ (NCol + 1))
            AddHandler PanelArray(i).Click, AddressOf panel_Click

            FrequencyBtnArray(i) = New Button
            FrequencyBtnArray(i).Name = "f" + Str(i)
            FrequencyBtnArray(i).TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft
            FrequencyBtnArray(i).FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
            FrequencyBtnArray(i).FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
            FrequencyBtnArray(i).FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.White
            FrequencyBtnArray(i).FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.White
            FrequencyBtnArray(i).Text = 0
            FrequencyBtnArray(i).Height = 30
            FrequencyBtnArray(i).Width = 45
            FrequencyBtnArray(i).Location = New Point(87, 102)
            FrequencyBtnArray(i).Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 6)
            FrequencyBtnArray(i).BackColor = Color.White
            FrequencyBtnArray(i).ForeColor = Color.Black
            PanelArray(i).Controls.Add(FrequencyBtnArray(i))


            HandBtnArray(i) = New Button()
            HandBtnArray(i).Name = "h" + Str(i)
            HandBtnArray(i).Text = Hands(i)
            HandBtnArray(i).FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
            HandBtnArray(i).FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
            HandBtnArray(i).FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Yellow
            HandBtnArray(i).BackColor = Color.White
            HandBtnArray(i).TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter
            HandBtnArray(i).Font = New Font("Segoe UI", 14)
            HandBtnArray(i).Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            PanelArray(i).Controls.Add(HandBtnArray(i))
            AddHandler HandBtnArray(i).MouseDown, AddressOf X_MouseDown

        Next
    End Sub
```

I added an event handeler "AddHandler HandBtnArray(i).MouseDown, AddressOf X_MouseDown"  for the mouse down event located at the bottom of the code.

```
Public Sub X_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
  
        sender.backcolor = Color.Red
   
End Sub
```

This event only works when I let off the mouse button. I included a picture of my hand matrix [image]

I want to for example click on AA in the top left and hold and drag my mouse over the different hands and  change the backcolor as the mouse goes over them while holding the left mouse button. I tried using the on enter event and it worked well but obviously it just changes everything without clicking the mouse. Also tried working with MouseEventArgs but ran into problems with EventArgs.

Comment: `MouseDown` would only be raised for the control that the cursor is over when you depress the mouse button. For the rest, you'd have to handle `MouseEnter` and test whether the mouse button is down at the time.

Comment: I thought the mousedown worked differently, what I think and what actually happens is two different things. I have tried to do the mouse enter but have no way to find out if the left mouse button is down? every solution I find online does not work, I would be nice to find a way to click the button on mouse enter or something along that line. Just have to keep digging

Comment: *"I [...] have no way to find out if the left mouse button is down"*. Of course you do. You're handling a `MouseDown` event, aren't you? What's stopping you setting a `Boolean` field in that event handler and then resetting it in the `MouseUp` event handler? That's something that you absolutely should have thought of yourself, but there's an even easier way that you wouldn't necessarily come up with: the `Control.MouseButtons` property.

Answer (score 0):

Each question can contain only one question. I will address the first question only. Ask a new question for the other question.

Notice in the MouseDown event procedure.

```
sender As Object
```

An `Object` does not have a `BackColor` property. This would be obvious if you had **Option Strict On** which you should **always** have it **On**. You can find this setting in the Project Properties on the Compile tab.

To solve this problem, cast sender to Button, then assign the color.

```
Private Sub X_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseDown
    Dim b = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    b.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
```

Comment: i end up getting the same results as before with the above code, it just clicks one red and stops. I need to change the backcolor of  all buttons the mouse goes over while holding down the left mouse button. jmcilhinney comment has me going in a different direction because I guess the mouse down event does not work like I thought it did. Also option Strict LOL I took a class on VB a couple years ago have not programed in a while, my teacher would be upset.